# Объясните почему не срабатывает animate в jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток, вопрос про jquery и функцию animate - есть блок у которого скрыта часть текста, внизу кнопка при нажатии блок должен плавно опускаться и открываться полностью, только мой код не работает, притом не работает в одну сторону, рабтает на закрытие плавно, а на открытие сразу открывается.

```
<style>
#moon-slide {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<div id="moon-slide">
<p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
```

adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
 aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
 ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim 
id est laborum

Подробнее

```
    $("#click-moon").click(function () {
            var moonSlide = $("#moon-slide");

            if (!moonSlide.hasClass("show")) {
                moonSlide.animate({
                    height: "100%"
                }, 1000, function () {
                    moonSlide.addClass('show');
                });
            } else {
                moonSlide.animate({
                    height: "79px"
                }, 1000, function () {
                    moonSlide.removeClass('show');
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Объяснение](http://habrahabr.ru/post/189252/)
Исправление, как вариант обернуть текст в еще один `div` и задавать высоту равной ему.

```js
 $("#click-moon").click(function() {
   var moonSlide = $("#moon-slide");

   if (!moonSlide.hasClass("show")) {
     moonSlide.animate({
       height: $('#moon-slide div.wrap').height() + 'px'
     }, 1000, function() {
       moonSlide.addClass('show');
     });
   } else {
     moonSlide.animate({
       height: "79px"
     }, 1000, function() {
       moonSlide.removeClass('show');
     });
   }
 });
```

```css
#moon-slide {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moon-slide">
  <div class="wrap">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aut libero voluptatum cupiditate necessitatibus deleniti quam voluptates dolores non quisquam porro impedit temporibus velit officia veritatis ad itaque culpa facilis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Error porro maxime repellendus dolorum similique officiis voluptate eaque perferendis inventore maiores voluptatibus iusto eius illum earum nulla laborum ullam alias non.
    lorem 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aut libero voluptatum cupiditate necessitatibus deleniti quam voluptates dolores non quisquam porro impedit temporibus velit officia veritatis ad itaque culpa facilis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Error porro maxime repellendus dolorum similique officiis voluptate eaque perferendis inventore maiores voluptatibus iusto eius illum earum nulla laborum ullam alias non.
    lorem 
  </div>
</div>
<button id="click-moon">Ok</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Спасибо за ссылку на объяснения.

Answer (score 0):

Не работает - в смысле? Класс добавляет?
height:100% должно задать высоту, совпадающую с родительской, в приведённом же примере высота родительского и дочернего блока будет одинакова (нет других дочерних блоков или заданной вручную величины).

В общем, нужен более полный код.

Comment: Он высоту добавляет и блок опускается, но мгновенно, вместо плавного спуска.

Comment: Возможно, стоит прочесть это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792302/animate-jquery-height-percentage . Вроде бы такая же проблема. Решение свелось, как я понимаю к расчёту абсолютной высоты, а не относительной.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать высоту в пикселях для animate:

```
    var moonSlide = $("#moon-slide");

$("button").click(function(){

    if (!moonSlide.hasClass("show")) {
        moonSlide.animate({
            height: "300px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            moonSlide.addClass('show');
        });
    } else {
        moonSlide.animate({
            height: "79px"
        }, 1000, function () {
            moonSlide.removeClass('show');
        });
    }   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/29pz1h4h/